Auto-scaling in kafka Consumer application
I'm new to kafka . And got basic understanding of kafka and it's configs .
My question is  :
If consumer application has 2 consumers in consumer group . Now if I auto-scale(increase) pods , will the consumer group contain 4 consumers?
Generally I want to understand how consumer application with one consumer group works in case of autoscaling?
I was thinking , if pods auto scaled , then number of consumers in the consumer group will also increase.

Yes your number of consumers would be multiplied by the number of processes running... However, you cannot have any number of active consumers in a group greater than the number of topic partitions
For that reason, cpu / memory based scaling isn't particularly useful because you would scale up, then on average, all replicas use less resources to process the partitions, causing you to scale back down and the group to rebalance. Consumer lag based scaling such as KEDA is more useful
